# Close current WebStorm instance with shortcut key on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, webstorm

I'm quite new with Mac OS X. I want to close my current WebStorm instance on Mac OS X with short cut keys, how can I do that?

I can use `Alt + F4` on Windows to do that, but on Mac OS X if I hit `command + Q` then all WebStorm instances are quit which is not my intent.

Please some experts give some advices, thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a Mac user .... but `File | Close Project`? If it has no shortcut already assigned (quite likely) then assign one at `Preferences | Keymap`

Comment: @LazyOne, works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a Mac user so cannot test it myself .. but `File | Close Project` should do the job for you.

Most likely it will not have any keyboard shortcut assigned by default... but you can easily assign one via `Preferences | Keymap`.

Comment: Thanks! I assigned `option+4`, and it works well! Hope there is way to synchronize my settings, so I don't need to do the mapping every time it was upgraded.